# $http post data appended to URL

Tags: angularjs

I have below *$http.post* request

```
var credentials = {username: "alpha", password: "beta"}

$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: baseUrl
            params:  credentials
            paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

This works fine but all credentials appended in the URL which was not a good approach as it display sensitive data

BUT when I change this  to

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: baseUrl,
            data:  credentials,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
});
```

this does not work?

what Is the issue?

if we do not send any headers than in browser I can see  the default

`Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8`

so why exactly server do not accept this application/json ?

Is that issue related to server or on the angular side?

Comment: have you tried encoding the username and password

Comment: The `Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8` is a default setting in `angular $http`

Comment: @Alok using yes i have tried with  `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: There is a typo in your second code quote, missing comma between `credentials`and `headers`

Comment: that's typo while writing question. Thanks. i'll fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: baseUrl,
            data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(credentials),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```